# I can't load blocks in my default.ctp

Tags: cakephp

I want to use the blocks statements in my application. I have a theme called: Boostrap. If I use only the statement **$this->element()** my elements load without problems, but if I use **$this->start()** and **$this->end()** I can't load my elements.

I try create a new file called index.ctp for a TestsController but the result is the same. I put **$this->fetch('header')** and **$this->fetch('footer')** in this file and nothing.

That's only an example of my real structure:

1. **Themed\Boostrap\Layouts\default.ctp**:

   ```
   <html>
       <head>
           <title></title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <?php $this->start('header'); ?>
           <?php echo $this->element('header'); ?>
           <?php $this->end(); ?>

           <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
           <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?> 

           <?php $this->start('footer'); ?>
           <?php echo $this->element('footer'); ?>
           <?php $this->end(); ?>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. **Themed\Boostrap\Elements\header.ctp**:

   ```
   <header>
       <h1>Hello World!!</h1>
   </header>
   ```
3. **Themed\Boostrap\Elements\footer.ctp**:

   ```
   <!-- app/views/themed/boostrap/elements/footer.ctp -->
   <footer>
       Copyright (c) Bla bla bla 2014.
   </footer>
   ```

**Details of my environment**:

- S.O: Windows 7
- CakePHP Versión: 2.4.4
- PHP Versión: 5.3.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're layout should define the block output, not the start and end methods:

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('header'); ?>
```

Then, in your view, you outline the block that will be outputted:

```
<?php $this->start('header'); ?>
<?php echo $this->element('header'); ?>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

Given this use case, blocks don't seem like the right solution.  Your element seems like it would be the only thing to display, in which you would output the element on the layout.  However, a more appropriate use case would be different output at a per-page level.

In your layout:

```
<?php echo $this->element('header'); ?>
<?php echo $this->fetch('header_block'); ?>
```

Page one:

```
<?php $this->start('header_block'); ?>
//Something unique to page 1
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

Page two:

```
<?php $this->start('header_block'); ?>
//Something unique to page 2
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```